# Overwrite Wordpress core functions

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to customize a core WP function using my `functions.php` file. Why won't my code work? This just adds a `<div class=\"shield\">` around the `ul`.

```
function my_start_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "\n$indent<div class=\"shield\"><ul class=\"sub-menu\">\n";
}
function my_end_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "$indent</ul></div>\n";
}

add_filter('start_lvl', 'my_start_lvl');
add_filter('end_lvl', 'my_end_lvl');
```

I don't know if it's related but I'm using the Carrington framework for my theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no filters named `'start_lvl'` or `'end_lvl'`. So your code is never called. I guess you want to change the output of a custom menu (your question is very vague).

If so – use a [custom walker](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14037/menu-items-description/14039#14039) instead.

Comment: Yes, all I really want is to change the output of the custom menu by wrapping the `<ul class="sub-menu">` inside a `<div class="shield">`. I'm still learning about using filters. Will check out the link.

Comment: It worked! So simply extending the class allows you to modify its methods.